# Telerik Radscheduler giving (403) Forbidden error on "exporttopdf"

Tags: asp.net, iis, telerik

The exporttopdf feature of radschedular is giving this error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

It works fine locally, but when deployed to the server it comes up with this error. I have given the user permission in `web.config`

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I understand 403 means the server understands the request but is refusing to process it. I am wondering if it has something to do with write permissions to some location on the server. I am also looking for a possibility of impersonation if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If the problem persists, please troubleshoot your issue following Telerik instructions here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-troubleshootings-pdfexport.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dalorzo, i have tried both before posting...none worked

Comment: Sorry to hear. I have personally struggled with this type of errors and telerik most of the times was a config issue. Hope this helps.